# Ccocs2d UIScrollView Stops Touch Response

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am using a uiscrollview in my cocos2d project, using modification of some cocos2d files and the great CCScrollView class I got from a SO link.  It is working fine but when I move to a next scene, the new scene is not responding to touches (whereas it was working fine before).

I am using iOS 5.1 & cocos2d 2.x.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you need to do this:

[aScrollView removeFromSuperview];

I'm not quite sure why since in the dealloc of CCScrollView you have:
    [self removeFromSuperview];

I guess its being retained somehow? Anyway, it works.